# How to hide an extra control from the "Toolbox"?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

Creating a library with new controls. It has 2 classes "HandySeparator - Basic" and "HandyHSeparator - Derived". The base class inherits the Control class. It contains properties that call the Invalidate() method. In the derived class, inside the OnPaint() method, the element is being drawn.

The catch is that after rebuilding the library, a control with the name of the base class appears in the "Toolbox", but I don't need it there.

** HandySeparator **

```
  public class HandySeparator : Control {
    private DashStyle dashStyle;
    public DashStyle DashStyle {
      get { return dashStyle; }
      set {
        dashStyle = value;
        Invalidate ();
      }
    }

  ...
  }
```

** HandyHSeparator **

```
  public class HandyHSeparator : HandySeparator {
  ...
  
  ... OnPaint(...) {
    /// Draw element
  }

  ...
  }
```

Comment: Decorate with [ToolBoxItem(false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem)

Answer (score 0):

** HandySeparator **

```
  [ToolboxItem(false)]
  public class HandySeparator : Control {
    private DashStyle dashStyle;
    public DashStyle DashStyle {
      get { return dashStyle; }
      set {
        dashStyle = value;
        Invalidate ();
      }
    }

  ...
  }
```

** HandyHSeparator **

```
  [ToolboxItem(true)]
  public class HandyHSeparator : HandySeparator {
  ...
  
  ... OnPaint(...) {
    /// Draw element
  }

  ...
  }
```